# Warum verlangt "über" hier den Akkusativ?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, accusative

> Verschiedene Stoffe aus unserer Umgebung werden **über die** Haut in den Körper aufgenommen.

Ich glaube, dass es nicht mit Bewegung zu tun hat, und deswegen kann ich das nicht begreifen, warum hier *über* auf diese Weise benutzt wurde?

Comment: Vgl *ob*, *obwohl*, leicht archaisch *ob der Haut*. Alternativ: Verschiedene Stoffe *auf* der Haut gelangen in den Körper. Auch: Wir fahren *ab* Hohen Wutzen (hinter Frankfurt Oder) direkt nach Poznan -- bzw. *über Hohen Wutzen*. Irgendwie so. Gute Frage!

Comment: Hier sind die Stoffe aber nicht "auf der Haut" sondern "aus unserer Umgebung", hier wird also die Haut quasi wie eine Zwischenhaltestelle angesehen, wo der Zug zwar langsam fährt, aber nicht vollständig zum Halt kommt und einfach weiter fährt, in dem Fall in den Körper hinein.

Comment: @Dan, bitte nicht in Kommentaren antworten.

Comment: ggf. könnte man hier *-her* vermuten, vgl *woher*, *daher*, *einher* ... sofern dessen Wurzel verwandt ist mit *hier* also auch Lat *co-* "mit, bei".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Ich glaube, dass es nicht mit Bewegung zu tun hat, …*

Man hat dir etwas falsch beigebracht. Bei den neun Präpositionen *an, auf, hinter, in, neben, über, unter, vor und zwischen* kommt es nicht auf Bewegung an. Sondern darum, ob ein **Ort** oder eine **Richtung** gemeint ist.

> Sie geht an den Strand.

Sie ist noch etwas weg vom Meer und geht **dorthin**. *Der Strand* ist also eine Richtung. Deshalb *an+Akkusativ*.

> Sie geht am Strand.

Sie befindet sich bereits auf dem Strand und geht **dort**. *Der Strand* ist also ein Ort. Deshalb *an+Dativ*.

---

Mit *über* funktioniert das genauso.

> Das Eichhörnchen springt über den Zaun.

Das ist eine Richtung. Der Zaun wird *überquert*.

> Das Eichhörnchen springt über dem Zaun.

Das ist ein Ort. Es springt oberhalb des Zaunes im Geäst herum.

Der Vollständigkeit halber auch noch mit *auf*:

> Das Eichhörnchen springt auf den Zaun.

Das ist eine Richtung. Es springt von irgendwo anders her **dorthin**.

> Das Eichhörnchen springt auf dem Zaun.

Das ist ein Ort. Es springt **dort** oben auf dem Zaun herum.

---

Dein Beispiel benutzt *über* im Sinne von *durch*.

> … werden über die Haut in den Körper aufgenommen.
>
> … werden durch die Haut in den Körper aufgenommen.

In beiden Fällen ist das wieder eine Richtung. *Durch* kann auch nur mit einer Richtung verwendet werden, und verwendet immer den Akkusativ.

---

Noch ein Wort der Warnung. Wird ein Hindernis *unterquert*, geht das nicht einfach mit dem Akkusativ. Stattdessen braucht man den Dativ und das Adverb *hindurch*.

> Der Fuchs gräbt sich unter **dem** Zaun **hindurch**.

Der Akkusativ ist bei *unter* für den Fall gedacht, dass etwas unter etwas anderes gerät und dort bleibt.

> Die Erbsen rollen unter **den** Kühlschrank.

---

An den Kommentaren sehe ich, dass die Sache offensichtlich auch Muttersprachlern immer noch unklar ist. Daher weitere Beispiele, die zeigen, dass es nicht um Bewegung, sondern nur um Ort oder Richtung geht.

> Ich schreibe in meine**m** Notizbuch auf jed**e** Seite das Datum.
>
> Der Wegweiser auf **der** Kreuzung zeigt auf **die** Kirche.
>
> Die Einpeitscherinnen schreien vor **der** Tribüne den Namen des Teams in **die** Menge.

Comment: *durch* wird durchaus auch stark abstrahiert verwendet und hat dann kam noch den Anschein einer Richtung, etwa werden *Richtungsangaben oft *durch* Präpositionen ausgedrückt* werden. Der Fragesteller spricht offenbar nicht gebrochen, daher ist die Erklärung des Grundprinzips wohl weder notwendig noch ohnehin ausreichend zur Beantwortung der Frage. Wenn das Eichhorn über die Haut springt, gelangt es nicht in den Körper. Wenn ich über Semantik rede, gelange ich nicht auf die andere Seite von Semantik (wenngleich die Metapher ausbaufähig wäre).

Comment: Dem Fragesteller wurde ganz offensichtlich etwas falsch beigebracht. Darf man das später nicht mehr korrigieren, nur weil er sonst keine Fehler macht?

Comment: Was soll denn an *durch Präpositionen* oder *über Metaphern* falsch sein, bzw. mit einer Richtung zu tun haben? Die Annahme, dass diese abstrakten Relationen sowie die in Frage stehende nicht ausschließlich aus Wegangaben abzuleiten sind entspricht durchaus einem natürlichen Sprachempfinden. Man sagt ggf. auch *von, mit der,* bzw. *durch die Haut*, die Richtung an sich ist also irrelevant. *Sie streiten sich ob der/des* (nicht sicher ob des grammatikalisch astrein sein sollte) hat auch nicht's mit *oben* zu tun, *aber* ist nicht mal als Präposition erkennbar, *wegen* hat wenig mit *Weg* am Hut

Comment: Weil dem Fragesteller ganz offensichtlich beigebracht wurde, dass die Unterscheidung zwischen Akkusativ und Dativ bei diesen Präpositionen mit Bewegung zu tun hätte. Das stimmt nicht. Alle Beispiele mit Bewegungsverben verwenden sowohl Akkusativ als auch Dativ. Beide Beispiele mit dem Verb *aufnehmen* verwenden den Akkusativ.

Comment: Ich habe weitere Beispiele ergänzt.

Comment: Na gut, den Versuch der Darstellung unterschiedlicher Fall-Beispiele (pun intended) habe ich nicht beachtet, denn die Frage betrifft sowohl *warum "über"* als auch *warum in dieser Weise*, wobei letzteres erst interessant ist, wenn ersteres geklärt ist, bzw. nur beides im Zusammenhang erklärt werden kann. Da die Wortwörtliche Übersetzung nirgendwo funktioniert, ist die Nachfrage doch wohl berechtigt. Dass es eben nicht *über der Haut* lautet, erklärt leider recht wenig. Zu erkennen, dass @Max dieser Unterschied nicht mal bewusst war, ist zwar eine bemerkennswerte Fähigkeit.

Answer (score 2):

Die Präposition "über" kann generell sowohl mit Akkusativ als auch Dativ verwendet werden, es kommt nur auf die Bedeutung an.
Es ist in diesem Fall als eine Bewegung aus dem Punkt A (Umgebung) in den Punkt B (Körper) über eine Art Haltestelle anzusehen, an der unser "Zug" nicht anhält. 
Hier sind die Stoffe nicht bereits "auf der Haut" sondern sie kommen(eine Bewegung!) "aus unserer Umgebung", hier wird also die Haut quasi wie eine Zwischenhaltestelle angesehen, wo der "Zug" zwar langsam fährt, aber nicht vollständig zum Halt kommt und einfach weiter fährt, in dem Fall in den Körper hinein. Ich hoffe das hilft :)

Comment: Ein *Ab*sorbtions-Prozess ist in der Regel relativ langsam und setzt Anlagerungen vorraus. Eine Salbe etwa wird *auf*-getragen. *überhaupt* wird nach der Begründung des grammatischen Falls gefragt, nicht nach der relativ offenkundigen Bedeutung.

Comment: @vectory Auch die Salbe wird *auf die* Haut aufgetragen.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is directional movement when something enters your body via your skin.

Comment: Die Frage ist derzeit auf deutsch gestellt :) Vielleicht ergänzt Du noch eine Übersetzung.

Comment: Did you mean "when something enters *into* your body"? *enter into* ist geradezu redundant, doch *in den Körper übergehen* ist eine stehende Wendung genauso wie *über [die Haut] ...*, die eben nicht allein aus dem naiven Gebrauch der Präpositionen erklärt werden kann.