# Warum Akkusativ bei "eine Geschichte über ..."?

Tags: preposition, dative, accusative

Ich weiß, dass es in der deutschen Grammatik Wechselpräpositionen gibt. Zum Beispiel:

> in, auf, hinter, zwischen, an, über, unter, neben, vor

Wir müssen entweder Dativ oder Akkusativ anwenden. Wir benutzen Akkusativ, wenn wir eine Bewegung haben, und beim Dativ ist es umgekehrt.

Warum benutzen wir den Akkusativ in diesem Satz?

> Dies ist die Geschichte über **meine** Erfahrung.

Warum nicht:

> Dies ist die Geschichte über **meiner** Erfahrung.

Es gibt keine Bewegung.

Comment: "Wir benutzen Akkusativ, wenn wir Bewegung haben" - das scheinen viele so zu lernen, aber es ist nicht richtig. "Ich gehe auf der Brücke" - dieser Satz drückt Bewegung aus, trotzdem wird *auf* mit Dativ verwendet. Der Akkusativ wird verwendet, wenn damit eine Richtung ausgedrückt wird. Wenn es sich nicht um einen physischen Vorgang handelt, hilft auch diese Regel nicht immer.

Comment: Thank you, is there a Grammer rule for this? I thought the above preposition are always known as Wechselpräposition. So if we are talking about something that's not related to physical stuff, then it would always be accusative?

Comment: The rule is: If *über* is used with the meaning of English *about*, accusative has to be used. If you hoped for a more general rule, then I'm sorry, but no, I don't see how this rule can be generalized.

Comment: Ich hab's schon mal geschrieben: Wenn man im Englischen "into" oder "onto" sagen kann, Akkusativ. Sonst Dativ.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warum verlangt "über" hier den Akkusativ?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54064/warum-verlangt-%c3%bcber-hier-den-akkusativ)

Comment: @Olafant Der Fall liegt hier etwas anders. Bei der verlinkten Frage geht es um einen physischen Vorgang, was hier nicht der Fall ist.

Comment: @tofro Diese Regel hilft hier nicht weiter. Den Satz oben würde man nicht mit into oder onto übersetzen, trotzdem wird Akkusativ verwendet.

Answer (score 3):

Erfahrung ist definitiv kein Ort, und auf eine Bewegung wird auch nicht abgezielt; über hat mehr Bedeutungen als Bezug auf einen Ort oder eine Bewegung:

- Wenn also 'über' im Sinne eines *Ort*es von räumlich oberhalb ('Der Ast hängt über dem Fluss'), dann wird sehr wahrscheinlich der Dativ verlangt
- Wenn 'über' im Sinne einer *Richtung* verwendet wird ('Wir gehen über den Fluss'), dann wird Akkusativ verlangt.
- Wenn 'über' im Sinne eines Themas verwendet wird ('ein Text über die Grammatik'), dann wird sehr wahrscheinlich der Akkusativ verlangt.

Comment: Danke, gibt es ein Grammatikthema dazu? Ich habe gedacht, dass "über" immer Wechselpräposition ist.

Comment: @PeterHaddad "Wechselpräpositionen" sind immer Präpositionen, die einen Ort beschreiben. In dieser Bedeutung beschreibt "über" keinen Ort, sondern ein Thema. In einem Wörterbuch, das die unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen von "über" auflistet, sollte auch dabeistehen, mit welchem Fall es jeweils verwendet wird; im Online-Duden ist das etwa Bedeutung Nr. 7, in de.wiktionary Bedeutung 5. Wenn "über" "about" bedeutet, wird es immer mit dem Akkusativ verwendet.

Answer (score 3):

Auf der [DWDS-Seite](https://www.dwds.de/wb/%C3%BCber#d-1-1-3) sind drei Bedeutungsvarianten der Präposition *über* angegeben:

1. räumlich
2. zeitlich
3. Sonderfunktion.

Das Beispiel aus der Frage fällt unter Punkt 3, also Sonderfunktion. Die von Dir angegebene Regel (die präziser lauten müsste: Ort->Dativ, Richtung->Akkusativ, anderes->?) bezieht sich nur auf die **räumliche** Bedeutung, denn nur in diesem Zusammenhang handelt es sich um eine Wechselpräposition.

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4position) merkt noch an (Hervorhebung von mir):

> Bei relativ festen Verbindungen von Verben mit bestimmten Präpositionen aus der Gruppe der Wechselpräpositionen **kann der zu verwendende Kasus nicht logisch erschlossen werden** und hängt von der jeweiligen Verbindung ab.

Answer (score 0):

Regeln bei natürlichen Sprachen treffen niemals zu 100%.

> Wir benutzen Akkusativ, wenn wir eine Bewegung haben, und beim Dativ
> ist es umgekehrt.

Diese Regel hilft, bei ca. 80% bis 90% den richtigen Fall (Dativ oder Akkusativ) zu verwenden. Bei "Geschichte über [Thema]" hilft sie nicht. Aber jeder wird den Satz auch mit dem Fehler "Dativ" verstehen.

Ich empfehle, viele Beispielsätze zu lernen. Dann findet das Gehirn selbst die Muster, wann welcher Fall richtig ist.